# Interacting with Petrel during interpretation process

Tags: ocean, petrel

Using Schlumberger Petrel and the Ocean framework, working with seismic interpretation.

During the process of interpreting (and autotracking), Petrel stores interpretation values (samples) in a collection on an interpretation object (e.g. HorizonInterpretation3D).

I would like to store some additional information on/in parallel with these samples. I have found suitable objects to store the extra info in, so that isn't any issue. However I have yet to find how to catch / intercept when the samples are produced/stored, so I know when to add the extra info.

I don't want to post-process the samples, I'd like to store the extra info in sync with the interpretation sample collection (the real sample data). Have yet to find any suitable event to listen to.

Anybody done anything similar with Petrel that can help?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I completely understand what you're trying to do.  A little more information would be helpful.  I'm assuming you're trying to read the `HorizonInterpretation3D.Samples` property and want to know when it changes?

You might try subscribing to `HorizonInterpretation3D.SelectedIndicesChanged`.  The documentation says that it is raised when the selected indices have changed.  I'm guessing that might happen during the process of interpreting.

You might also just try polling while the interpretation process is active.